Docker compiled bytecode not equal to Remix deployed bytecode
Any ideas to what I can do to fix this?
I am using Go-Ethereum to compile a deploy a smart contract and the deployment just hangs.
The contract compiles and deploys using Remix on Sepolia.
The byte code is:
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

Compiling the same contract using a script:
docker run -v /home/user/Documents/crypto-projects/arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.24 --allow-paths=/sources/sol-flattened -o /sources/solc-output --optimize --overwrite --bin --abi /sources/sol-flattened/Base.sol
Compiler run successful. Artifact(s) can be found in directory "/sources/solc-output".
abigen --abi /home/user/Documents/crypto-projects/arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/solc-output/Base.abi --bin=/home/user/Documents/crypto-projects/arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/solc-output/Base.bin --pkg=api --type=Base --out=/home/user/Documents/crypto-projects/arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/api/Base.go

The compiled byte code is:
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

This bytecode is different from the bytecode generated from Remix and one potential issue why the deployment fails.
This is my deployment code:

func Run(contractName string) {
    fmt.Println("Contract deploying...")
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(wallet.Sepolia.PrivateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("Not OK " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA)
    nonce, err := connection.RPC.Client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }
    // Set the gas price and gas limit
    suggestedGasPrice, err := connection.RPC.Client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }
    fmt.Println("suggestedGasPrice: ", suggestedGasPrice)

    contractString := util.ContractBytes(contractName)
    fmt.Println("contractString: ", contractString)
    contractBytecode := common.FromHex(contractString)

    // Estimate gas limit
    msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        From:     fromAddress,
        To:       nil, // To is nil for contract deployment
        Gas:      0,
        GasPrice: suggestedGasPrice,
        Value:    big.NewInt(0),
        Data:     contractBytecode,
    }

    gasLimit, err := connection.RPC.Client.EstimateGas(context.Background(), msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to estimate gas: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Gas Price: %s\n", suggestedGasPrice.String())
    fmt.Printf("Gas Limit: %d\n", gasLimit)

    // Example of creating a transaction for contract deployment
    chainID, err := connection.RPC.Client.NetworkID(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to get network ID: %v", err)
    }

    tx := types.NewTx(&types.LegacyTx{
        Nonce:    nonce,
        To:       nil,
        Value:    big.NewInt(0),
        Gas:      gasLimit,
        GasPrice: suggestedGasPrice,
        Data:     contractBytecode})

    signedTx, err := types.SignTx(tx, types.NewEIP155Signer(chainID), privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to sign transaction: %v", err)
    }

    // Send the transaction
    err = connection.RPC.Client.SendTransaction(context.Background(), signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to send transaction: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(signedTx.Hash().Hex(), "waiting to be mined...") //<--------------hanges here
    startTime := time.Now()
    receipt, err := bind.WaitMined(context.Background(), connection.RPC.Client, signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }
    fmt.Println("Mining took", time.Since(startTime))
    fmt.Println("Token tx:", tx.Hash())
    fmt.Println("Token cost:", tx.Cost())
    fmt.Println("Token gas limit:", tx.Gas())
    fmt.Println("Token gas price:", tx.GasPrice())

    if receipt.Status == types.ReceiptStatusSuccessful {
        fmt.Println("Token deployed successfully")
    } else {
        reason, err := getRevertReason(receipt)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err.Error() + whereami.WhereAmI())
        }
        log.Fatal(reason + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }
}


Are you using the exact same EVM and compiler versions? Also, if enabled optimization, then are you using the exact same numbers of optimized runs?

Yes, I have identical compiler versions solc 0.8.24, EVM cancun, 200 runs optimization.
